# How can I select a class that dynamically added with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have added class active on scroll to .content-single with jQuery. I also want to add different class to #with-scroll on the basic on which active class is added dynamically.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="with-scroll" class="single with-scroll">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="outer-navigator"><a href="#" class="tl-navigator three">3</a></div>
          <div class="col s12 center-align third-title">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          </div>
            <div class="col m6 s6">
                <div class="text-content">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum,<br> 
                    in real time.</h3>
                    <div id="content-single-one" class="content-single">
                    <a href="#scroll1"></a>
                      <i class="material-icons">supervisor_account</i>
                      <h4 id="scroll1" class="section scrollspy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum, your workers, your team and
                         companies perform side by side - in real-time.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="content-single-two" class="content-single">
                    <a href="#scroll2"></a>
                    <i class="material-icons">av_timer</i>
                      <h4 id="scroll2" class="section scrollspy">Lorem ipsum</h4>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum with the help of screenshotting,<br>
                        screen recording orem ipsum monitoring.<br> 
                        Know exactly what was done and when.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="content-single-three" class="content-single">
                    <a href="#scroll3"></a>
                    <i class="material-icons">group_work</i>
                      <h4 id="scroll3" class="section scrollspy">Lorem ipsum</h4>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum, your worers, team and compa nies <br>
                      perform side-by-side - in real-time. <br>
                      Iden tify bottlenecksand getan eagle-eye view <br>
                      of your business. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col m6 s6" id="screen-sticky">
            <div class="screen">
                <img src="images/macbook.png">
                  <div class="inner one">
                    <img src="images/screen-1.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="inner two">
                    <img src="images/screen-2.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="inner three">
                    <img src="images/screen-3.png">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And Here is Jquery I am trying to select

```
$(function() {
  $("#content-single-one.active").each(function(){
    $("#with-scroll").addClass("one");
  });
  $("#content-single-two.active").each(function(){
    $("#with-scroll").addClass("two");
  });
  $("#content-single-three.active").each(function(){
    $("#with-scroll").addClass("three");
  });
});
```

Comment: Your example logic is strange.  Why are you doing an each over a single element?  And if active is not on any of those elements at the beginning, none of those will execute.  You'll need to do your logic at some point after adding the class to one of those elements.  In which case you don't need an if.  You know which one you just added active to...

Comment: Suppose, #content-single-two will get class .active on scroll

Comment: Ok, so at that point do whatever you need to do to the other things based on you just put the class on that element...  $('selector') doesn't find things that do not exist yet.  If you change something to match that selector after the point of it running, it will not find them.  That selector is not being continuously re-evaluated.

Comment: When adding class statically it's working but when i try to add this class .active with jquery it's not working

Comment: Right cause that logic is running on page load.  Only once.  And like i said above, it does not continuously re-evaluate.  Take a look at the answer below for doing the logic on scroll.

Comment: Where's the code where you are adding the class dynamically?  That's where you should be changing the with-scroll  class (probably use a data attribute too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify if has the class active

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($("#content-single-one").hasClass('active')){
        $("#with-scroll").addClass("one");
    }else if($("#content-single-two").hasClass('active')){
        $("#with-scroll").addClass("two");
    }else if($("#content-single-three").hasClass('active')){
        $("#with-scroll").addClass("three");
    }
})
```

Comment: Selectors inside a scroll event are inefficient as scroll fires a lot.  Better to cache them outside in variables and use the variables in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You should modify for your codes:

```js
  $(document).on('change', 'yourSelectingClassId', function(){
    //your code...
  });
```

I thought it would be nice to add. Because I tried many method, finally it worked. I hope anyone in need sees it.

Comment: this is helpful, but could be more helpful if you were to give more extensive explanation, and refine the usage a bit. It is an example of event delegation, which is an important idea and worth explaining. ALSO, there are potentially very large performance implications to using document at the top instead of a much closer parent. It could be very helpful to discuss that as well.